# Run script which is stored at GCS | Airflow | VM

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, virtual-machine, airflow

I have a script at GCS bucket. I want to run the script in my airflow dag using BashOperator. **The airflow is present in a VM**.
My constraints are that I cannot copy that script in VM and run because it has some jobs and connections running inside it. If I copy the script I will have to copy the dependant jars and files as well.
I tried using `gsutil cat <script path in bucket> | sh`  but it is not working.
I also came across post for accessing the bucket-file using below code but I do not know how to use it in BashOperator or to run it.

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket('test_bucket')

blob = bucket.get_blob('temp_files_folder/test.txt')
```

Any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

To use Cloud Storage files as local, you can use [GCSFuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) that mount a bucket in a folder and then you can use the file directly from your VM, but the file never left Cloud Storage location.

Comment: With GCSFuse will it run the script on source(bucket) or VM ?
If it runs on VM then the paths mentioned inside script will be searched in VM which will cause issues !

Comment: You can run nothing on Cloud Storage, it's only a storage system. However, you can run stuff on a VM. So, in your case, the script run on the VM. If the dependencies are also stored in the bucket and you have relative path, it should work. If the dependencies have full path definition, maybe mounting the bucket in the right directory could solve the issue.

Comment: Yes , the dependencies are stored in the bucket. What do you mean when you say 'relative path'.
Sorry for such questions.I am new to it.

Comment: You have absolute path that starts from the root of your system, like this `/this/is/absolute/path` and a relative path that start from the current directory, like this `./this/is/relative`. If it's relative, doesn't matter where you mount the bucket with GCS fuse, because the path is relative to the current script directory. If it's absolute not.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use Airflow VM (current), you have to use another environment (VM) to run.  I think the simplest way is to wrap your Java program into a Docker container, add needed packages and run it, for example in Google Cloud Run/Cloud Function.
Instead of storing Java file (-s) in GCP, store Docker image in DockerHub, Google Cloud Registry, or another service.

You can pass connection settings as env variables or command arguments while running the container.
Obviously, you can use the current Airflow VM (if Docker is installed) to run the Docker container.
Some helpful links:

1. Airflow DockerOperator https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html
2. Create workflow for Cloud Run/Function https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/workflows.html